# With the SO homepage redesign, can server-side highlighting and hiding be implemented?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, ignored-tags, tag-watching

As the new Stack Overflow homepage relies on interesting and ignored tags to decide what order questions should be placed in, caching is no longer a reason to explain why filtering is done client-side. [As](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40750/so-interesting-tags-highlighted-using-javascript) [requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34910/filter-tags-server-side-instead-of-client-side) [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24228/highlighting-questions-with-interesting-tags-is-very-slow), can we attach classes to those questions server-side instead of client-side?

Answer (score 2):

We could possibly do this for all the homepage tabs, interesting highlighting on the server is also doable.

However, ignoring on the '/questions' tabs (when hide ignored is on) is a much harder problem, as it would require a redesign of the caching code.